# Close Excel without saving in PHP

Tags: php, excel, com, save

I am using the Excel.Application COM object on my windows server.

Currently I am using :
`$this->excel->Quit();`
but it launches a diablog box asking to save.

**I would like to know if we can force shutdown of the excel file without saving.**

Edit : I could add that the file is in fact modified but I call a "Save as" before quitting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._application.quit) suggests that you can set the Saved property to True or set the DisplayAlerts property to False to suppress the Save dialog.